Merging shapefile with data file with coordinates
I have a shapefile 'shp' with boundaries, and I have a data .csv file with coordinates and some values. I want to join the df to shp, so that each coordinate/observation would be in the correct zone/boundary.
What I've done, but I get an error:
shape_df <- st_join(shp, df, join = st_intersects)

(st_contains gives the same error)
Data types:
> class(shp)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

 > class(df)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

> st_crs(shp)
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: OSGB36 / British National Grid 
  wkt:
PROJCRS["OSGB36 / British National Grid",

>st_crs(df)
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: OSGB36 / British National Grid 
  wkt:
PROJCRS["OSGB36 / British National Grid",
    BASEGEOGCRS["OSGB36",

Error:
Error in UseMethod("st_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_join' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial')"

What am I doing wrong? How do I solve this?

st_join() is an sf function, so requires both files to be sf objects. Try library(sf) then shp <- st_as_sf(shp) then df <- st_as_sf(df) then shape_df <- st_join(df, shp). Obviously, install sf first if you haven't already.

It seems to make more sense to append polygon attributes to your points, so shape_df <- st_join(df, shp) instead of shape_df <- st_join(shp, df).
